# Function in a bash script: command not found

Tags: bash, shell

I'm learning bash and I'm trying to call this function that will copy files from another directory to another directory where the files are in reverse alphabetical order. whenever i try to run the script it says "thesorter not found". Should i assign the function to a variable?

I get "command not found". When I sue the code in the function with calling or making the function it runs perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash
sourcedir=$1
targetdir=$2

if [[ $# != 2 ]]
then
  echo -e "Error: Expected two input parameters.\nUsage: ./sortedcopy.sh <sourcedirectory> <targetdirectory>"
exit 1




elif [[ ! -d $1 ]]
then
  echo -e "Error: Input parameter #1 '$1' is not a directory.\nUsage: ./sortedcopy.sh <sourcedirectory> <targetdirectory>"
 exit 2


function thesorter() 
{
          mkdir $2
        cd $2
        path2=$(pwd)
        cd $(cd -)
        cd $1
        i=1
        for file in $(ls -r )
        do
                cp $file $path2/$((i++)).$file
        done
}


elif [[ ! -d $2 ]]
then
        thesorter $sourcedir $targetdir

else
 echo "Directory '$2' already exists. Overwrite? (y/n)"
 read answer
 if [[ $answer = y ]]
 then
       rm -r $2
       thesorter $sourcedir $targetdir
 fi
   exit 3
fi
```

Comment: Maybe you should make the function defined out of if statements (to the beginning).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies many problems with the code (including the cause of the "command not found" error).  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: yeah that works thanks. It's been a really long day...

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're encountering, "thesorter not found," is likely due to the placement of your `thesorter` function. Bash functions should be defined before they are called.

In your script, you have defined the `thesorter` function inside an `elif` block, which means it will only be defined if the condition in that `elif` block is met. If none of the conditions leading to the `elif` block is met, the function will not be defined, and you'll get the "command not found" error when you try to call it.

To fix this issue, you should define the `thesorter` function before the conditional statements. Here's the modified script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the thesorter function before conditional statements
function thesorter() {
    mkdir "$2"
    cd "$2" || exit 1
    path2=$(pwd)
    cd - || exit 1
    cd "$1" || exit 2
    i=1
    for file in $(ls -r)
    do
        cp "$file" "$path2/$((i++)).$file"
    done
}

sourcedir="$1"
targetdir="$2"

if [[ $# != 2 ]]
then
    echo -e "Error: Expected two input parameters.\nUsage: ./sortedcopy.sh <sourcedirectory> <targetdirectory>"
    exit 1
elif [[ ! -d $1 ]]
then
    echo -e "Error: Input parameter #1 '$1' is not a directory.\nUsage: ./sortedcopy.sh <sourcedirectory> <targetdirectory>"
    exit 2
elif [[ ! -d $2 ]]
then
    thesorter "$sourcedir" "$targetdir"
else
    echo "Directory '$2' already exists. Overwrite? (y/n)"
    read -r answer
    if [[ $answer = y ]]
    then
        rm -r "$2"
        thesorter "$sourcedir" "$targetdir"
    fi
    exit 3
fi
```

In this modified script, the `thesorter` function is defined at the beginning, ensuring it's available for use throughout the script. Also, I made some minor improvements to handle directory paths with spaces correctly by wrapping them in double quotes.